# How to not run a python exe if it already exists in task manager

Tags: python

If I have a python executable compiled to exe, how can I check if it's already running in task manager and if so, avoid running a new instance of it?

```
import wmi
if (c.Win32_Process(name="Script.exe")):
    sys.exit()
else:
    #script.exe's code
```

The code above uses the wmi module to check if the program is already running, then stop the new instance from running. The problem with it is that the script will never run. This is due to the fact that when script.exe is ran for the first time, it shows up immediately in task manager. The WMI module detects this and closes it as soon as it opens. I confirmed this by renaming the executable to Script2.exe, which runs the program just fine.

Is there any way to properly check if a python exe is already running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file doesn't remove itself when the system shuts down, you can try this:

Create a temp .txt folder anywhere on your system, then prevent any other programs from accessing it by making python think that's "currently in use by another program". For example:

```
import threading
import os

pth = os.getcwd() + '\\text.txt'

if os.path.exists(pth):
    try:
        os.remove(pth)
    except PermissionError:
        sys.exit()
else:
    open(pth,"w+").close()

f = open(pth,"w+")
def loop():
    while True:
        pass
threading.Thread(target=loop).start()
```

If another instance of the program is ran, you will get a PermissionError and the program will close.

Comment: Neat solution. Just note this _only_ works on Windows. And even then, it might also break in odd circumstances, for example if the lockfile is stored on a network share, however unlikely that may be.

Answer (score 2):

One general method for this is *lock* files. Sometimes also called *pid* files.

When the process starts, it creates a file in a predefined location. If the process starts and the file exists, you assume the process is already running. Once the process exits, it should clean up its lock file.

```py
import os
LOCK_FILE = "C:\\Path\\To\\myapplication.lock"

if os.path.exists(LOCK_FILE):
    print(f"LOCK FILE {LOCK_FILE} already exits. Exiting")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    with open(LOCK_FILE, 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'{os.getpid()}')

try:
    main()
finally:
    try:
        os.remove(LOCK_FILE)
    except OSError:
        pass
```

There's some better handling that could be done, but this is the basic idea.

You could also write your program to run as a [Windows service](http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/) (a daemon).

Not ideal, but you could also improve upon your solution by checking the current `pid` AND the program name.

```py
for process in processes:
    if process.pid != os.getpid() and process.name == script_name:
        sys.exit(1)
```

Part of the reason this is not ideal is because the executable name is not guaranteed (as you noted, the filename can simply be changed and this breaks)

Comment: This solution is perfect for most python scripts. However, my script has to constantly run in the background. Since there's no real "end" to the process, when the lock file is removed, the process continues. This allows it to be called again while the previous version is still running.

Comment: This solution still works in this case. `when the lock file is removed` The lock file will not be removed on its own. The only case it should be removed is _when_ the program stops. If the program never stops (`main()` runs forever), the file will never be removed. The `finally:` clause would be for situations like if the system shuts down. Python will try to cleanup the file before the system turns off, so the process can start when the process is started after the system comes back up.

Comment: Didn't actually think the entire thing through- this does in fact work!

Comment: Glad this works for you. I also added a couple alternatives as well as food for thought :-)

Answer (score 0):

`is_process_exists` returns `True` if process exists, `False` if not:

```
import psutil

def is_process_exists(process_name):
    return bool([p for p in psutil.process_iter() if psutil.Process(p.pid).name() == process_name])
```

Comment: I think the problem in this case is that the script itself is trying to check if the process is running... but of course it will _always_ be running if the program checks for its own name :-)